# Populating hidden items on button click in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-button

I have 2 `Button` one below the other and I have other 4 hidden `Button` besides them . I want to unhide 2 of those `Button` when my first `Button` is clicked and organize them exactly below that `Button` while the other 2 `Button` should be unhide when 2nd `Button` is clicked exactly below the 2nd `Button`. Now if I place these hidden `Button` they will occupy space in between my visible `Button`, which I dont want .Is there any way by which i can push my 2nd visible `Button` down and show my 2 of the hidden `Button` onclick of 1st visible `Button`.

Comment: Add some drawings of what you are trying to achieve please? Doesn't matter if they are crude

Comment: You should have provided your existing code...

Comment: I have my 2 buttons one below the other. So i want to push down the second button in order to get my hidden buttons visible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `setvisibility` to achieve that.

```
button= (Button) findViewById(R.id.play);
    button.setVisibility(1);
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
             //when button is clicked show/hide buttons
             button2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
             button3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }
    });
```

you can also use `button.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);` instead of `button.setVisibility(View.GONE);`

Comment: I have my 2 buttons one below the other. So i want to push down the second button in order to get my hidden buttons visible

Comment: my code is just a example of how to use setvisibility to hide/unhide buttons. modify it according to your needs.